# Does bash support back references in parameter expansion?

Tags: bash, regular-expression, string, variable-substitution

I have a variable named `descr` which can contain a string `Blah: -> r1-ae0-2 / [123]`, `-> s7-Gi0-0-1:1-US / Foo`, etc. I want to get the `-> r1-ae0-2`, `-> s7-Gi0-0-1:1-US` part from the string. At the moment I use `descr=$(grep -oP '\->\s*\S+' <<< "$descr"` for this. Is there a better way to do this? Is it also possible to do this with parameter expansion?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`ksh93` and `zsh` have back-reference (or more accurately<sup>1</sup>, references to capture groups in the replacement) support inside `${var/pattern/replacement}`, not `bash`.

`ksh93`:

```
$ var='Blah: -> r1-ae0-2 / [123]'
$ printf '%s\n' "${var/*@(->*([[:space:]])+([^[:space:]]))*/\1}"
-> r1-ae0-2
```

`zsh`:

```
$ var='Blah: -> r1-ae0-2 / [123]'
$ set -o extendedglob
$ printf '%s\n' "${var/(#b)*(->[[:space:]]#[^[:space:]]##)*/$match[1]}"
-> r1-ae0-2
```

(`mksh` man page also mentions that future versions will support it with `${KSH_MATCH[1]}` for the first capture group. Not available yet as of 2017-04-25).

However, with `bash`, you can do:

```
$ [[ $var =~ -\>[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+ ]] &&
  printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
-> r1-ae0-2
```

Which is better as it checks that the pattern is found first.

If your system's regexps support `\s`/`\S`, you can also do:

```
re='->\s*\S+'
[[ $var =~ $re ]]
```

With `zsh`, you can get the full power of PCREs with:

```
$ set -o rematchpcre
$ [[ $var =~ '->\s*\S+' ]] && printf '%s\n' $MATCH
-> r1-ae0-2
```

With `zsh -o extendedglob`, see also:

```
$ printf '%s\n' ${(SM)var##-\>[[:space:]]#[^[:space:]]##}
-> r1-ae0-2
```

Portably:

```
$ expr " $var" : '.*\(->[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)'
-> r1-ae0-2
```

If there are several occurrences of the pattern in the string, the behaviour will vary with all those solutions. However none of them will give you a newline separated list of all matches like in your GNU-`grep`-based solution.

To do that, you'd need to do the looping by hand. For instance, with `bash`:

```
re='(->\s*\S+)(.*)'
while [[ $var =~ $re ]]; do
  printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  var=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
done
```

With `zsh`, you could resort to this kind of trick to store all the matches in an array:

```
set -o extendedglob
matches=() n=0
: ${var//(#m)->[[:space:]]#[^[:space:]]##/${matches[++n]::=$MATCH}}
printf '%s\n' $matches
```

---

<sup>1</sup> back-references does more commonly designate a pattern that references what was matched by an earlier group. For instance, the `\(.\)\1` basic regular expression matches a single character followed by that same character (it matches on `aa`, not on `ab`). That `\1` is a back-reference to that `\(.\)` capture group in the same pattern.

`ksh93` does support back-references in its patterns (for instance `ls -d -- @(?)\1` will list the file names that consist of two identical characters), not other shells. Standard BREs and PCREs support back-references but not standard ERE, though some ERE implementations support it as an extension. `bash`'s `[[ foo =~ re ]]` uses EREs.

```
[[ aa =~ (.)\1 ]]
```

will not match, but

```
re='(.)\1'; [[ aa =~ $re ]]
```

may if the system's EREs support it.

Answer (score 9):

You want to delete everything up to the first `␣->␣` (not including the "arrow") and after the last `␣/` (including the space and slash).

```
string="Blah: -> r1-ae0-2 / [123]"
string=${string/*->/->}
string=${string/ \/*}
```

`$string` will now be `-> r1-ae0-2`.

The same two substitutions would turn `-> s7-Gi0-0-1:1-US / Foo` into `-> s7-Gi0-0-1:1-US`.

Answer (score 3):

Answering this definitively is impossible without knowing the exact format *every* message takes. However, as a general approach you can print certain specific fields using `cut`:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 2 <<< '-> s7-Gi0-0-1:1-US / Foo'
s7-Gi0-0-1:1-US
```

Or you can [print every nth column using `awk`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22354082/96588):

```
$ awk -F' ' '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=4) print $i }' <<< '-> r1-ae0-2 / [123], -> s7-Gi0-0-1:1-US / Foo'
r1-ae0-2
s7-Gi0-0-1:1-US
```